# TFS 2018 - Build and Release stuck on Loading

Tags: tfs

I have noticed once in a while Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2018 will get stuck on 'Loading...' whenever I go to "Builds" or "Releases" menu. This seems to be independent of the Team Project.

If I change the url of the server eventually it works:
http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs
http://mytfsserver.mydomain.net:8080/tfs
http://myalias:8080/tfs
http://myalias.mydomain.net:8080/tfs

I am TFS Admin so I should have the security rights to see everything.

There is no error message, just a "Loading..." that never goes away.

Is there a log that TFS uses?

Comment: Have you checked the event view of your TFS server? Did this only occurs on your machine or for everyone in your team? Besides, when you said change the rul of the server eventually it works. You have post 4 url, which one is not working and which one works properly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is happening to the whole team, one more than others. The url changes, sometimes one will work and other times it will not, it is very strange, not sure if the change of urls is reseting something that I am not aware of.

Comment: Sounds incredible, never heard this kind of issue, why your team are using so many urls? I'm afraid this may make the issue more complicated. Suggest you focus on  one url and find a way to reproduce the issue continuously. Besides double check your network environment and if you are behind a proxy, remove the proxy and try again.

Comment: I am not trying to use multiple urls. I just found that jump between those urls would fix the issue. But in the end it had nothing to do with it. I just posted a answer to the issue. Maybe this will help someone in the future. Or even myself again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So called Microsoft and they were able to fix the issue.

It was the account that TFS was running as. I changed from a domain account to the NETWORK SERVICE and this fixed the issue.

I have no idea why that would be the case since the domain account that I was using before had Admin rights on the local machine and on the SQL Server machine.

I also don't understand how NETWORK SERVICE was able to login to SQL server on another machine. I wonder the if logged in user is my old account. Not sure.

Well, but since then it fixed my issue. Go Microsoft Tech Support :)

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark your own reply as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know I can do that :)